# Spring, Interceptor's excludePathPatterns function is not working properly

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring Framework and I wanted to write an interceptor and I wrote it eventually and it is working fine. 
but at a point, I dont want my interceptor to intercept the request that is when user wants to logout and the session is being invalidated. But it is not happening as per my expectation.

I am adding interceptors by extending the **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter** and by utilizing the **addInterceptors** method and here is the code.

```
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    super.addInterceptors(registry);
    registry.addInterceptor( loggerInterceptor );
    registry.addInterceptor( authenticationInterceptor ).excludePathPatterns("/invalidate");   
    }
```

Have I done anything wrong here.?
excludePathPatterns - > My URL ends with /invalidate. So please guide me, how to device a proper pattern.

Comment: I have used following methods but it always runs the authentication interceptor.
/**/invalidate*,
**/invalidate*,
*/invalidate*,
/**/invalidate,
**/invalidate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried as below?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter 
{
  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) 
  {
    registry.addInterceptor(new MyCustomInterceptor())
            .addPathPatterns("/**")
            .excludePathPatterns("/foo/**");
  }
}
```

[Reference](http://www.jacobquatier.com/posts/2013/07/15/spring-mvc-mapped-interceptors/)

Refer this [java doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors) for better understanding.

Comment: I've tried this exact same thing and it's not working for me. My interceptor is catching every request, not respecting the `excludePathPatterns(...)`. I have a simple controller that I want to process a specific request, but can't get the request due to the fact that my interceptor is catching all request.

Comment: With Spring 5+, WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated, you need to implement WebMvcConfigurer (interface).

Comment: @HatemJaber I have the same problem, for no reasons the interceptor is trapping every request. The only solution I found so far is checking the path inside the interceptor.

Comment: @Chandra Sekhar Can I have the excludePathPatterns without the addPathPatterns ? I assume if I don't specify the addPathPatterns, it'll default to everything.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe your code triggers another error,the url path changed to another url(/error etc),then the /error url path that you have not excluded,pls check your code or debug a breakpoint as [this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akaPh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's Unnecessary add:

```
addPathPatterns("/**")
```

MappedInterceptor.java:

[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question; it's a comment on another answer.  For those that are confused about the relevance of `MappedInterceptor`, an instance of it is created behind the scenes when an interceptor is added.  See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistration.java  Note at the bottom of that class, in the `toArray` method, that if the `List` of included patterns is empty then `null` is returned rather than an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to debug the whole FrameworkServlet of Spring, and somewhere, an exception was thrown saying: "No parameters named hashId".

Turned out my requestParam wasn't named hashId but id, so the interceptor was correctly applied to that service url path.

Make sure the excludedPattern starts with "/" and is requested with the parameter names exactly as defined in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same issue while implementing the similar requirement. Please try below in your code if you are **using Spring 5+** version.

```
@Configuration
public class BasicInterceptorAppConfig implements **WebMvcConfigurer** {

    @Autowired
    YourCustomInterceptor yourCustomInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry interceptorRegistry){
        interceptorRegistry.addInterceptor(yourCustomInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/admin.html", "/swagger-ui.html");

    }

}
```

Please user WebMvcConfigurer for Spring 5+ version. Hope this may help someone who is looking similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing trailing slash.

`registry.addInterceptor(fooInterceptor()).excludePathPatterns("/internal/bar**");`
instead of

`registry.addInterceptor(fooInterceptor()).excludePathPatterns("/internal/bar/**");`